# Arduino 'Error communicating...unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes' PySerial

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to connect to my MultiWii over PySerial, however I keep getting this error.

`Error communicating...unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '$M<\x00ll'`

This is the part of the code that's failing:

```
BASIC="\x24\x4d\x3c\x00"
MSP_ATTITUDE=BASIC+"\x6C\x6C"
ser.write(MSP_ATTITUDE)
```

I've tried encoding the strings with `.encode()` in which I get this error:

```
Error communicating...'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I've tried bytearray(MSP_ATTITUDE,'ascii') and get the previous error.

I'm only asking this because this error circle doesn't really make sense. Can anyone help? I can provide more information regarding the code if it'll help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't create strings.

Strings are for unicode text, which `\x24\x4d\x3c\x00` is not.

For arbitrary bytes, use byte strings. You can construct those directly using `b''`.

```
>>> type('foo')
<class 'str'>

>>> type(b'foo')
<class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
BASIC = b"\x24\x4d\x3c\x00"
MSP_ATTITUDE = BASIC + b"\x6C\x6C"
```

So that they are treated as `bytes` objects and not unicode strings.