# TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '\x08'

Tags: python, unicode, pygame

I read this answers:

- [python3 pySerial TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642855/python3-pyserial-typeerror-unicode-strings-are-not-supported-please-encode-to)
- [Arduino 'Error communicating...unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes' PySerial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692285/arduino-error-communicating-unicode-strings-are-not-supported-please-encode)

But I was not understanding it. In my case I have `chr(code)` going into the `serial.write` functions.

Do I write `b'chr(8)'`?

```
import serial
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class RCTest(object):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    self.ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout = 1)
    self.send_inst = True
    self.steer()

def steer(self):

    while self.send_inst:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print("entered for loop")

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                print("entered event.type == KEYDOWN")

                key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                print("pygame.key.get_pressed() running")

                # complex orders
                if key_input[pygame.K_UP] and key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    print("Forward Right")
                    self.ser.write((chr(6))

                elif key_input[pygame.K_UP] and key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    print("Forward Left")
                    self.ser.write((chr(4))

                # simple orders
                elif key_input[pygame.K_UP]:
                    print("Forward")
                    self.ser.write((chr(8))

                elif key_input[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    print("Reverse")
                    self.ser.write((chr(2))

                # exit
                elif key_input[pygame.K_x] or key_input[pygame.K_q]:
                    print('Exit')
                    self.send_inst = False
                    self.ser.write((chr(0))
                    self.ser.close()
                    break

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.ser.write((chr(0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RCTest()
```

After running the program, I press DOWN ARROWKEY.

```
entered for loop
entered for loop
entered for loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
entered event.type == KEYDOWN
  File "C:/Users/../rc_control_test.py", line 58, in <module>
pygame.key.get_pressed() running
    RCTest()
Reverse
```

Comment: If you want to send the number 8, but in `bytes` format, then you simply do `self.ser.write(struct.pack('B', 8))`, if you want a character, you do `self.ser.write(bytes(chr(8), 'UTF-8'))`.

Comment: Perfect man, it works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `b'\x08'` or `bytes([8])` are other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to encode to bytes:

```
"string".encode()
>> b'string'
```

Therefore, you can probably write like this:

```
self.ser.write(("string".encode()))
```

Else, if you want to write one character at a time:

```
self.ser.write("A".encode())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried this `self.ser.write(bytes(chr(8), 'UTF-8'))` and it works perfectly!

Comment: OK Daniel Lee `self.ser.write("8".encode()) works even better because now i can control my car via Arduino!!!

Comment: Or just `self.ser.write(b'string')`.